# Debugging Go tests in Visual Studio Code

Tags: unit-testing, go, visual-studio-code

On my Windows machine, I have Visual Studio Code installed. To run tests manually, I go in console to projects folder and enter

```
go test main_test.go
```

It works perfectly.

[image]

But I have a situation in which I need to debug my test to understand what's going on.

For this I open launch.json and add a configuration

```
  {
        "name": "Tests",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "test",
        "remotePath": "",
        "port": 2346,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "env": {},
        "args": [
           "main_test.go"
            ],
        "showLog": true
    }
```

After I press F5 I have

```
2017/03/29 13:28:11 server.go:73: Using API v1
2017/03/29 13:28:11 debugger.go:68: launching process with args: [./debug.test main_test.go main_go]
not an executable file
Process exiting with code: 1
```

Any ideas why this error occurs and what executable it's looking for?

Comment: Try to specify 'program' property in configuration with executable file '${workspaceRoot}/main_test.go'

Comment: That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To launch debugger for test I added one more configuration for launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Code",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "remotePath": "",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "args": [],
            "showLog": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Test Current File",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "test",
            "remotePath": "",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "program": "${file}",
            "env": {},
            "args": [],
            "showLog": true
        }       
    ]
}
```

Also this configuration does not support tags. All tags in test files have to be disabled

```
// +build unit
...
```

Comment: Mode test is the key thing here and you saved my life! Thanks a lot as it's so difficult to find proper solution when I tried to debug unit test in vscode, what a combination!

Comment: Does anyone know what the change would be to debug a "go test" case remotely?

Comment: This solution used to work for me, now it doesn't. I'm not sure what changed but I had to change `"program": "${file}"` to `"program": "${relativeFileDirname}"` because VSCode was not finding the other files in the package.

Comment: In fact MODE = TEST was the answer I did no found in any other place! Thank you for share it with us.

Comment: I am pleased with this package to handle multiple conf: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DarrenLevine.auto-debug
You can configure to run "Test Current File" for "*_test.go" and "Code" for other go files to run the main program.

Answer (score 4):

For the mode, you can select `auto` which would choose either `debug` or `test` depending on active editor window.

All options for mode are `auto`, `debug`, `test`, `exec`, `replay`, `core`.

The resulting `launch.json` would look like:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch file",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${file}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was not working because I named my file main_tests.go instead of main_test.go